# Mount Windows NAS from RHEL

Tags: terminal, rhel, mount, nas

I am trying to mount a NAS from a RHEL-7.4 VM. This is in a closed environment, so no internet whatsoever.

I can ping the sever without issue (IP and FQDN both work) and I can see the shares that are available using `smbclient -L`, so I'm assuming that I'm authenticating OK, but when I try to actually mount it I keep getting errors. I've been researching this for over a week and seen several solutions that only include a different command variation, but very few (if any) that actually explain the *why* behind the error and how to best fix the issue.

**What I've Tried**

SMBFS (all versions):

```bsh
$ sudo mount -v -t cifs -o user=<usr //<server>/share  /mnt/share
---
$ sudo mount -v -t cifs -o user=<usr> //<server>/share /mnt/share
---
$ sudo mount -v -t cifs -o vers=<vNum>,user=<usr> //<server>/share /mnt/share
---
$ sudo mount -v -t cifs -o vers=<vNum>,user=<usr> //<server>/share /mnt/share
---
$ sudo mount -v -t cifs -o vers=<vNum>,user=<usr>,domain=<domain> //<server>/share /mnt/share
---
$ sudo mount -v -t cifs -o vers=<vNum>,user=<usr>,sec=krb5 //<server>/share /mnt/share
---
$ sudo mount -v -t cifs -o vers=<vNum>,credentials=$HOME/<credFile> //<server>/share /mnt/share
```

NFS:

```bsh
$ sudo mount -v -t nfs <server>:/share /mnt/share
---
$ sudo mount -v -t nfs <server>:/share /mnt/share -o user=<user>
```

**Errors:**

> `mount error(2): No such file or directory` 
>   `mount error(112): Host is down`

Comment: To start with, you'll have to know how the sharing is configured on the Windows side. Is `nfs` even available? Is it using `NTLM` and if so, which version? Are you sure that you are connecting as a user who has access to the share?

Comment: I'm assuming `nfs` is available; it (seems to) successfully authenticate and try to attach the share. I'll give the `NTLM` a shot. I just need to do `sec=NTLM`, right?

Comment: I tried every `sec=<option>` variation available, and each time I got `mount error(2) No such file or directory`.

Comment: The option is `sec=ntlm`. Of course, it also depends on whether NTLM is being used on the file server and which version. If you are sure that `nfs` is available and it successfully mounts them why do you need to mount it with `cifs`?

Comment: But it's not successfully mounting; I get `mount error(2): No such file or directory` with both `cifs` and `nfs`. My *assumption* is that I'm authenticating successfully, but something else after that isn't lining up and causing everything to break. However, i don't know enough about how `mount` works to say that definitively.

Comment: Nasir, In your first post, you mentioned that I need to know "how the sharing is configured on the Windows side." How/where do I go about finding that information?

Comment: You'll have to ask the admin or engineer who is in charge of the server.